# NSNumber numberWithInt results in NSNull when added as object to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnumber, nsnull

This is probably a rather basic problem, but try as I might I can't find the reason that causes it.

I wrote the following code:

```
    NSMutableDictionary * myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray * values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

        // create an object that can become a key in an NSDictionary
        CustomObjectAdoptingNSCopy * someKey = [[CustomObjectAdoptingNSCopy alloc] init];

        // create a random value that will become an object for myDictionary ...
        int someValue = rand()%10;

        // ... and which also gets to be an object in the values array, provided it isn't already stored there
        if ([values indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someValue]]==NSNotFound)
            [values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someValue]];

        // now associate someValue with someKey in myDictionary
        [myDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someValue] forKey:someKey];
    }

    // read the data in myDictionary enumerating the NSArray values
    for (NSNumber * aValue in values){
        NSArray * objectsForValue = [myDictionary allKeysForObject:aValue];
        // now the data from objectsForValue are being used ...
    }
```

The problem manifests when `objectsForValue` is empty, which does not happen all the time but regularly. If I am not very much mistaken this is logically impossible unless `[NSNumber numberWithInt:someValue]` gets interpreted as NSNull when added as Object to `myDictionary`, while the same expression gets treated as an object when it is being added to the NSArray `values`.

And logging `myDictionary` I noticed that this is indeed what's happening. Can anybody explain to me why?

Comment: Why are you making an array and a dictionary? Why not just set the object for key and then enumerate over the dictionary?

Comment: Show the logged dictionary. There's *nothing* here that will magically introduce `NSNull` objects, which are not the same as `nil`. Show the code for how `CustomObjectAdoptingNSCopy` implements copying *and* equality.

Comment: There are many, many more plausible explanations than "an NSNumber is getting magically turned into NSNull". For example, your dictionary could be getting modified behind your back, you might have a typo in the original code that is not present in this obviously fake example, etc. It's hard to say for certain without the actual code, but if I were you, I would investigate much more thoroughly before jumping to a conclusion like magical NSNulls.

Comment: @Ken Thanks for the comment! I checked the implementation of the NSCopying protocol. I allocate a new instance in `copyWithZone` and return it - as I did in similar situations more than once without getting into trouble. But I found, that if I `return self` and leave the allocation to an implementation of `mutableCopyWithZone` my code works fine. I can't say that I really understand why that is, but the import thing is, my app does not crash anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't overridden `-isEqual:` and `-hash`, then copies of your `CustomObjectAdoptingNSCopy` don't equal each other. `NSObject`'s default implementation of equality is object identity. Since `NSDictionary` copies the keys but copies don't equal the original, you can't retrieve anything from the dictionary unless you ask it for its keys and use those. The originals won't work.